# How to setup authentication for accessing google cloud external ip with a key

Tags: authentication, flask, web-applications, google-compute-engine, jwt

Lets say we are invoking a rest application (flask in python ) deployed in GCP Compute engine using external ip associated with the compute instance running the flask code. Its response is being accessed using a urlFetchApp function from Google AppScript editor window. I am looking for a way to send the request using a secured key in the requesting link to get authorized by the google cloud and provide access. Ultimately whoever is accessing the google cloud compute engine instance external ip should only permitted if they have correct key while sending the request.

Comment: The best answer depends on what "key" is. Is this some unique number that you are generating? Is it a Signed JWT? Is it an OAuth Token? Details make for better answers. If you are looking for a Google solution for Compute Engine, use an HTTP Load Balancer in front of your VM instance and turn on IAP (Identity Aware Proxy). https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/tutorial-gce

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to develop a function that handle the authentication from your code, in this [link](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask) there are examples about how to implement authentication to a flask rest API application.

In this [link](https://geekflare.com/securing-flask-api-with-jwt/) there is another example to use and generate JWT token for flask API

The requests on Compute engine are not secured by Google since this is not a managed service.

Comment: Thanks for the URL. it helped me to get familiar with other techniques

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the link @JorgeHDZ i stumbled across the same link but the challenge now is to how to send the post request from Appscript. The site mentions to use a curl command as below to send the username and password . I want to replicate the same using json request through Appscripts but not sure how 
Ex given in site: 
**curl -u miguel:python -i http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks**

Json request i am trying

```
function myFunction(){
var url ='http://x.x.x.x:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks';
var options = {
    "method": "get",
    "auth": {
        "user": "miguel",
        "password": "python"
    }
}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
Logger.log(response.getContentText())
}
```

Any way on how to improve this request so it was properly communicate with the @auth.verifypassword decorator in flask code will be helpful

Comment: I found app script infromation on this link https://www.labnol.org/code/19871-get-post-requests-google-script

Comment: Thanks for the url i was able to proceed ahead by just replacing the method from "get" to "post" and using the auth.loginrequired decator in the flask application which will auto capture the "auth" related key value pairs in the appscript body.sequence of decorators while app roting in flask is 

auth.verifypassword   
  app.route("/example", method = ['GET'])
   loginrequired
   def example function():